# On hover pop up size limited within table data.How to display it completely?

Tags: css, angularjs, html-table, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap on hover pop up(using data-toggle and data-content) in ng-repeat as below .

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in docDetails">
                    <td class="uploadedDocs"> {{row.EnrollmentDocumentTypeName}}</td>
                    <td class="uploadedDocs">
                        <div class="col-sm-2" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Uploaded By:{{row.DocumentUploadedBy}}  Uploaded Date :{{row.ChangedDateTime |   date:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}" data-trigger="hover">
                            {{row.FileName}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Now after I added it inside a `<td>`, the pop up content is getting limited by td size, I want the pop up to be displayed fully, and not restricted inside table data.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it using `data-container="body"`